# Ext.data.JsonP request Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I want to make call to authenticate user and get back token in json file. I use Ext.data.JsonP but when I call it display Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in browser.
I can't use Ext.Ajax because it's on another domain.
Here is code:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        url : 'myurl',


        success : function(result) {


            alert('success');
        },
        failure : function(result) {
            alert('failure');
        },
        callback : function(result) {
            alert('callback');
        }
    });
```

And this is expected result:

```
{"token":"MTAwNTI7V00yWkdVMFlqZDtkMDExZWU4YmU4ZTdlM2RjYzNkYzU3OThhYWViYjk4YmMxMzY2NTY2"}
```

Can somebody tell me what's causing Unexpected token : error?
Or other way how to get response.
Thanks

Comment: i am gettign the same error - what was the fix for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is not valid JSONP? JSONP is just a JavaScript function with a (JSON) object being passed to it:

```
callback({"token": "..."});
```

`Ext.data.JsonP#request` will automatically send a `callback` paramater; so your server just needs to read that and use that parameter as the callback function.